# Aggregate Array into a Dataframe with a group by

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I need to aggregate an array inside my `DataFrame`.

The `DataFrame` was created in this way

```
splitted.map(lambda x: Row(store= int(x[0]), date= parser.parse(x[1]), values= (x[2:(len(x))]) )  )
```

**Values** is an array

I want to do think like this

```
mean_by_week = sqlct.sql("SELECT store, SUM(values) from sells group by date, store")
```

But I have the following error

> AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'sum(values)' due to data type mismatch: function sum requires numeric types, not ArrayType(StringType,true); line 0 pos 0"

The array have always the same dimension. But each run the dimension may change, is near 100 of length.

How can aggregate without going to a RDD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matching dimensions or not sum for `array<>` is not meaningful hence not implemented. You can try to restructure and aggregate:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, array, size, sum as sum_

n = df.select(size("values")).first()[0]
df = sc.parallelize([(1, [1, 2, 3]), (1, [4, 5, 6])]).toDF(["store", "values"])
df.groupBy("store").agg(array(*[
    sum_(col("values").getItem(i)) for i in range(n)]).alias("values"))
```

Comment: After using the provided code, I am able to generate a separate column. But, the aggregated value is of type Array<double>, however, I need it to be type double. Can you please help?